# how to find out object difference between two images?

Tags: c++, opencv

In my project i am having image 1 contains geometric cad model and another image 2 having same geometric cad model but some thing is missing in that.So i have to find out that is that both parts are same or not?if not then want to give the location in image 2 where the part is missing by indicating some mark on image.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly here is a way:
You import the images and run the subtract method from opencv on them followed by np.any.

Here is a sample code (using python):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread("banana.jpg")
image2 = cv2.imread("banana2.jpg")

difference = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

result = not np.any(difference) #if difference is all zeros it will return False

if result is True:
    print "The images are the same"
else:
    cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", difference)
    print "the images are different"
```

**C++ version:**

```
auto image1 = cv::imread("banana.jpg");
auto image2 = cv::imread("banana2.jpg");

cv::Mat difference;
cv::absDiff(image1,image2,difference);

auto result=cv::countNonZero(difference)>0;

if(result){
    std::cout << "The images are the same";
}
else{
    cv::imwrite("result.jpg", difference)
    std::cout << "the images are different";
}
```

Comment: @ ibininja i don't have a knowledge of python will u please give it in c++?

Comment: @ibininja please correct me if I made some mistakes

Comment: Thanks.This result shows the both images overlapping on each other and difference is shown by white color.But i want difference will be shown on only one image giving some marks or arrow or something different color because white is not good to visible.how can i?